# Rational Points on $y^2=x^3-86069^5$

Tags: elliptic-curves, rational-points

The analytic rank of the Mordell elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-86069^5$ indicates that it has rank 2. However, deriving a set of generators, and hence the regulator, is proving to be a little bit of an intractable problem.

I'm posting this question in the hope that someone may have investigated this curve already and, as such, may be able to help me out with some of the points on the curve.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

As further background, I have been involved in a small group searching for values of #Sha > 1 up through the ranks of Mordell curves, currently from ranks 0 to 9.

To date we have been able to progress to a rank 9 curve were #Sha would seem to be at least equal to 9. The details of which may be seen at the [NMBRTHRY Archives](https://listserv.nodak.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=ind1208&L=NMBRTHRY&P=23667).

Kevin.

Comment: You might be able to prove that your elliptic curve has analytic rank exactly 2 by finding an exact formula for L(E,1). The point is that your elliptic curve has CM and for some CM elliptic curves like $x^3+y^3=p$ with $p$ prime, you have an effective lower bound on $L(E,1)$ when nonzero. See for example the article 'Which primes are sums of two cubes ?' by Rodriguez-Villegas and Zagier.

Comment: Why this particular curve?  Do we already have generators for all curves $y^2 = x^3 \pm p^5$ with prime $p<86069$ for which the analytic rank
exceeds $1$?


Comment: @Noam  There are a couple of curves that we would like to get the generators for, this one and y^2=x^3+443^5.  I posted this particular question in the hope that the generators were already known and so save a lot of processing time.
The main interest here is deriving the value of #sha(k*-27).

Comment: @François, Thank you for the suggestion.  I'll certainly follow up on it.

Comment: @Kevin thanks, but I still wonder why these particular curves.
If the $k=443^5$ curve would do as well then it should be tried first
because the generators ought to be be much more accessible:
the real period is proportional to $k^{-1/6}$, so if all else that goes
into BSD is about the same (conjecturally $L^*(E,1)\sim k^{\pm\epsilon}$)
then the regulator should grow as about $p^{5/6}$, and (for rank $2$)
the generators' heights as $p^{5/12}$; since $(86069/443)^{5/12}$ is about $9$,
this would reduce the heights from about $10^3$ to $10^2$ which should be
feasible with present descent tools.

Comment: @Noam - I've been running mwrank on 443^5 for a while to see what happens, maybe I'll get a result over the next week or two.  With 86069^5, this was known to be a difficult curve to attack.  Our intent, in this instance, is to attempt to determine #Sha for both E(k) and E(-27*k) on this curve. 

Comment: Well mwrank does only 2-descents, which usually aren't enough to bring
a point of height ~100 within reach.  But (following J.Weigandt's 
**magma** computation) here the ConjecturalRegulator is only 2612.64 (those $k^{\pm\epsilon}$ factors can make a big difference in practice), so you can expect to get at least one point.  Meanwhile I ran FourDescent
and PointsQI, and got $(46160353/42^2, 438188195663/42^3)$, which **mwrank** may have found by now (height $18.29$), and ...


Comment: ... a second generator with $x$-coordinate $N/D^2$ where
$$N = -18508992109435642648272765287494073191969714723796327,
$$
$$
D = 857276411592231840843144
$$
(height $120.9$), which **mwrank** surely could not find in reasonable time.


Comment: @Noam - Thanks for the second generator. We don't have access to magma here and are using tools written by Cremona and Stoll along with a few custom pari/gp scripts and a bit of C code. I obviously need to look at an implementation of 4 descent when I get some time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This particular curve, which I'll call $E$, may be quite challenging. The analytic rank is probably 2, but as far as I know, the only way to prove this is to show that the algebraic rank is not 0. Assuming the analytic rank is 2 and the full BSD formula, the product of the Regulator and the order of the Tate-Shafarevich group is approximately 1435241.110225344. (Using the command ConjecturalRegulator(E); in MAGMA).

Since the the rank is probably 2, I would guess that the Shafarevich-Tate group is trivial, so that the regulator is quite large.

In this case a 4-Descent was feasible. Below are the genus 1 curves in $\Bbb P^3$ that represent the elements of the $4$-Selmer group modulo torsion. If we can find points on these curves, they will map to points of infinite order on $E$.

```
> E := EllipticCurve([0,-86069^5]); 
> ConjecturalRegulator(E); 
1435241.11022534407264592039437 2
> TD := TwoDescent(E); 
> SetClassGroupBounds("GRH"); 
> time FD := [FourDescent(C) : C in TD]; 
Time: 3.890
> FD;
[
    [
        Curve over Rational Field defined by
        15*x1^2 + 111*x1*x2 + 4*x1*x3 + 10*x1*x4 - 38*x2^2 - 95*x2*x3 + 67*x2*x4
            - 54*x3^2 - 14*x3*x4 - 71*x4^2,
        31*x1^2 - 71*x1*x2 - 69*x1*x3 - 23*x1*x4 + 9*x2^2 - 92*x2*x3 - 24*x2*x4 
            + 35*x3^2 - 148*x3*x4 + 168*x4^2,
        Curve over Rational Field defined by
        35*x1^2 + 26*x1*x2 + 41*x1*x3 + 61*x1*x4 + 54*x2^2 + 11*x2*x3 + 25*x2*x4
            + 68*x3^2 + 3*x3*x4 - 78*x4^2,
        36*x1^2 - 138*x1*x2 - 38*x1*x3 + 127*x1*x4 + 25*x2^2 + 42*x2*x3 + 
            47*x2*x4 + 81*x3^2 - 12*x3*x4 + 60*x4^2
    ],
    [
        Curve over Rational Field defined by
        21*x1^2 + 13*x1*x2 + 13*x1*x3 + 44*x1*x4 - 32*x2^2 - x2*x3 - 18*x2*x4 - 
            45*x3^2 + 24*x3*x4 - 238*x4^2,
        5*x1^2 - 14*x1*x2 + 122*x1*x3 + 268*x1*x4 + 26*x2^2 + 6*x2*x3 + 
            149*x2*x4 - 57*x3^2 - 23*x3*x4 - 78*x4^2,
        Curve over Rational Field defined by
        4*x1^2 + 49*x1*x2 + 34*x1*x3 + 26*x1*x4 + 26*x2^2 - 33*x2*x3 - 74*x2*x4 
            + 53*x3^2 - 74*x3*x4 + 111*x4^2,
        38*x1^2 - 84*x1*x2 + 3*x1*x3 - 88*x1*x4 - 29*x2^2 + 27*x2*x3 - 154*x2*x4
            + 5*x3^2 - 234*x3*x4 - 120*x4^2
    ],
    [
        Curve over Rational Field defined by
        7*x1^2 + 78*x1*x2 + 106*x1*x3 + 62*x1*x4 - 21*x2^2 - 26*x2*x3 + 22*x2*x4
            + 34*x3^2 - 25*x3*x4 - 118*x4^2,
        33*x1^2 + 2*x1*x2 - 14*x1*x3 + 106*x1*x4 + 48*x2^2 - 33*x2*x3 + 
            165*x2*x4 + 69*x3^2 + 31*x3*x4 - 26*x4^2,
        Curve over Rational Field defined by
        7*x1^2 + 46*x1*x2 + 33*x1*x3 + 23*x1*x4 + 13*x2^2 + 36*x2*x3 - 108*x2*x4
            - 69*x3^2 - 88*x3*x4 + 145*x4^2,
        19*x1^2 - 28*x1*x2 - 14*x1*x3 + 8*x1*x4 + 150*x2^2 - 52*x2*x3 + 
            190*x2*x4 - 46*x3^2 + 33*x3*x4 + 248*x4^2
    ]
]
```

I searched for points on these curves up to height $10^9$ and didn't find any, which isn't that surprising given that the regulator is probably so large. Maybe an $8$- $9$- or $12$-descent would help, but I'm not sure since the regulator looks to be so large.

I've come across a lot of curves like this one, and honestly I don't know what to do other than spend a great deal of time implementing higher and higher descents, which will require better and better architecture for working with algebraic number fields.

Finding points on curves with rank at least 2 is much harder than the rank 1 case, where a non-torsion Heegner point can be constructed. I've often wondered if the notion of visibility of Mordell-Weil groups could be useful here to prove that the rank is 2. There might be some hope since this curve is just a sextic twist of a very simple elliptic curve, but I have no idea what other abelian variety one would try to use to "visualize" the Mordell-Weil group.

EDIT: Found a rational point!

Since this is a Mordell curve, it has a 3-isogeny. So ThreeDescentByIsogeny(E); works in magma. This, together with the 4-Descent above, can be patched together with Tom Fisher's 12-Descent code. Running PointSearch(C, 10^15) on all the 12-covers, I found one rational point on a 12-cover. This maps back to the HUGE point $P = (r/t^2, s/t^3) \in E(\Bbb Q)$ where

$$t = 1064315237527062416197829497356636659645269584461099593669088031745089037672135800872679057089531240249644479256790731579010363138838881840905955995370777995601208434305913644468575606,$$

$$r = 280330358182289626756155234063598323321079390462341827366518987565228009421332474964681906370265513552399459534408574388270067641670339702167066942312699829200035334349465315027488431491497462250163493458119988220147933027219004129214673758569410719992144923411319943555067857245550021843686621974171705862665984304126540657354963027685841117202627482318291749321065520239017,$$

and

$$s = -3894169495021322706664690332034015776766200723677334488117565017206832575610394605401029654682981124772659459298812689312208671041841435640288530899795853801784491292694434680924857836480106291120205903428248497270005655966231499766892812223437056078000735443855989892506051021805114412318184420256429821942583648074219767873044937972437645324252633026228735728785740079828040374108087622426272823877167554852034435686184476368398239806496596492675365799418315372050294056476779196364271993469777717240193414071588739725730054647942389914059081838403974737198837$$

Magma (and sage) says the canonical height of $P$ is 862.589016739449. $P$ has infinite order and is not a multiple of another point.

I'll keep looking for more points on 12-covers, but there should be a smarter way to look for a second generator since we know conjecturally what the regulator is supposed to be, at least up to division by an integer square (the order of Sha).

Second Edit: Second generator found by Tom Fisher!

I received email from Tom Fisher who got wind of this example thanks to Kevin Acres and Mark Watkins. He used some more careful minimization techniques for 12-covers which made it much easier for him to find the second generator $Q = (u/w^2, v/w^3)$ where

$$w = 182114807484521200807106885195433046250677033531559359037472093313104122418454868285361195199297225042175078422885282555317033956772998359062866824462985656413093380882725866443379879289096885109176415930832786071510257551923931848041894889001647111552913336376307990237676516910188887260245394301062683134535223719019999940520792408074037957510825778941886955164545102$$

$$u = 6409818948420000148009253515371033320765674658334995509069337486116156301741657451140832523716129416946553724548364793698626405777843956622076380997023235142487299844326278568312577933328949209325079504842164930964499614652180484249884310193722360960206856049327696413372088438499522988880226096525828673972002212550418445757426791463589511241682169507191857404060127705996714164059762587639453970388047710151991644286292989545241436751637355865317439825495449344823977758797766025325026099986880721224779341838599953004314077314458400203457162779096001177667625960285991372461677348744634118572760595736047817251613300845834732694598202906328385669708044981270667425075403152129513088853355196780998723571290752400352784381236905647783762282233$$

$$v = 9541721267275526440336656075081968921795973155189044266523956895286489666750185996900611973660561530367870689843326743006933458752307224811373451969681421106849987021781748740069623362388923316032840282833074591791294185661671902447470420594105932470690611184875968605655279379274234568020070054315280341961704988604471445169462057158108739193383808091705876229256447451432215635271166605138776098284834213663487614216411244364417456782497135614069447487775516105502956819954881548171764933506408613533330700718054166278531808088754093650937927404096948372079871885150489168059803000137727292308698902319300888120656605108547686297443217509881949442132801485412503095358513515604711600740777338910658971774981045705755311582771691405245163713860189075823123694400673272454942433819801867842344237200886745700934179591344744409814700762619336056693409131813436072830610006822421568399180878828865624130779460438617259828853398661927306856293129558704629256045989464076110208592569978237366668166654822438426674566555490387538893656476099175185704061248678944708728574308512767720849000403950411614279621166869036373101$$

This height of $Q$ is 1715.46805605884712533431816634 and the regulator is actually 1435241.11022534407264592039437 as BSD predicts if Sha(E/Q) is trivial.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, we'll dedicate a bit of processing time to this and see if it won't crack.

Comment: An 8-descent took about 1500 seconds in Magma with class group bounds set to GRH. I searched up to height 10^12 and the 8-covers (this took about another 1000 seconds) and didn't find anything yet, but the coefficients of the 8-covers are very very large.

Comment: @Jamie - Amazing job. Thank you so much for that.  Surely this has to be close to, if not actually, a record height found so far!

Comment: @Kevin - Thank you, but I only did the tiniest fraction of the work that went into finding this point. Tom Fisher's work on 12-Descent and Noam's ideas on point searches implemented in MAGMA by Mark Watkins are essential parts of these calculations which I only vaguely understand.

Comment: @Jamie - It's unfortunate that I don't have Magma here, only Pari/gp.   I'll have to hunt around to see if I can find any scripts for descent in that language.  Other than that I'll try and understand the process and write my own, which, I'm sure, will be a big learning curve for me.


Comment: @Kevin - I am interested in the long term project of implementing higher descents in Sage. Jeechul Woo has some GP scripts for descent via 3-isogeny, which is applicable to Mordell curves.

Comment: @Jamie - I have a script that will generate points on curves of special types.  For example on y^2=x^3+k, where k=4*86069^100+1, I can construct a point of height 3033.804673.  But I needed a big value of k to get there.

Comment: I suppose the goal should be to maximize h(P)/log|\Delta_min(E)|, although conceivably this could still get arbitrarily large. It will not get arbitrarily small though by Szpiro's conjecture. See http://modular.math.washington.edu/mcs/archive/Fall2001/notes/12-10-01/12-10-01.ps

Comment: Congratulations!  Not a record because Heegner-point techniques
go well beyond descent when they're available, but possibly a
record or near-record height for a curve of rank $>1$.
$$ $$
My point-search techniques aren't that abstruse -- basically
all I'm using (besides LLL) is that the image of an 
$\epsilon$-interval under an analytic map is contained in a box of size
$\ll\epsilon\times\epsilon^2\times\epsilon^3\times\cdots$.
Descent technology is much more complicated.  (And Jeechul Woo's
$3$-descent formulas won't help here: they need a rational
$3$-torsion point, not just a $3$-isogeny.)


Comment: @K.Acres: It's not hard to make examples where the height is comparable to
the height of the coefficients.  If $k=t^2+1$ then $(x,y)=(-1,t)$
is a rational point; here $k = 2 \cdot 86069^{50}$.


Comment: In what time was PointSearch(C, 10^15) computed? Since E is isomporphich to E':  y^2 = x^3 - 1/86069 can you please try PointSearch(E',10^15) (the coefficients are much smaller). 

Comment: @Noam: Thanks! It's nice to get one of these higher descents to work out. I've been looking at curves with bigger conductors recently and getting discouraged.

@joro: My most recently search of the 12-covers was up to 10^21 and took about 8 1/2 hours. No new points to report. A big part of the descent procedure is minimizing and reducing the 12-covers so that the points on them are as small as possible. So changing the model should not help in this case. 

Comment: UPDATE: PointSearch(C,10^24) for all 12-covers C took about 3 days and found no new points. I'll try to run something bigger on my department's servers.

Comment: @Jamie - Thank you for your continuation of this search.  It's very much appreciated. Meanwhile, one of our group will be at the 'Selmer Groups, Descent and the Distribution of Ranks' conference at Warwick between 24th and 28th September.  Hopefully something useful will come out of that. 

Comment: @Kevin: thanks. I was really hoping to go to that conference but unfortunately I have other obligations, and can't afford it. I would suggest speaking to Tom Fisher about the possibility of patching together 8-descents and 3-descents to get a 24-descent. I'm not sure if it is feasible for this curve or not, but if it were, the other generator shouldn't be too hard to find.


Comment: UPDATE: PointSearch(C, 10^27) for all 12-covers C took about 11 days. Nothing to report. Trying 10^30.

Answer (score 4):

Tom A. Fisher has kindly identified the second generator for this curve, at a height of $1715.46805605884712533431816634$, and with a regulator of $1435241.11022534407264592039437$.

Many thanks to Tom for this impressive workout of his 12 descent code.

P2:= E![6409818948420000148009253515371033320765674658334995\
509069337486116156301741657451140832523716129416946553724548\
364793698626405777843956622076380997023235142487299844326278\
568312577933328949209325079504842164930964499614652180484249\
884310193722360960206856049327696413372088438499522988880226\
096525828673972002212550418445757426791463589511241682169507\
191857404060127705996714164059762587639453970388047710151991\
644286292989545241436751637355865317439825495449344823977758\
797766025325026099986880721224779341838599953004314077314458\
400203457162779096001177667625960285991372461677348744634118\
572760595736047817251613300845834732694598202906328385669708\
044981270667425075403152129513088853355196780998723571290752\
400352784381236905647783762282233/33165803105124219179549823\
283035686736456675469805935767692444023551658331570872880192\
989613282702564119725223095907264020401187622726619827641022\
070312051693797896281152446136738277971480729817095517412821\
500028443753503375569153920181215330943019021452618523429306\
154890615692258509116181263907011892227215259838198394721409\
844161749103601296315808769202168882630133040496609244967027\
573328564357038779635203477380317914882271609699042932772428\
958728775525114597825318245131110925771677312456670934287090\
438610192382893431121092876711361026457071789640268657157836\
261872615922281539370618784278612205624356072354848973487567\
580677872395212361402429095761079520397611920420171112702594\
975559992623826579984003799616507192963910592190404, 9541721\
267275526440336656075081968921795973155189044266523956895286\
489666750185996900611973660561530367870689843326743006933458\
752307224811373451969681421106849987021781748740069623362388\
923316032840282833074591791294185661671902447470420594105932\
470690611184875968605655279379274234568020070054315280341961\
704988604471445169462057158108739193383808091705876229256447\
451432215635271166605138776098284834213663487614216411244364\
417456782497135614069447487775516105502956819954881548171764\
933506408613533330700718054166278531808088754093650937927404\
096948372079871885150489168059803000137727292308698902319300\
888120656605108547686297443217509881949442132801485412503095\
358513515604711600740777338910658971774981045705755311582771\
691405245163713860189075823123694400673272454942433819801867\
842344237200886745700934179591344744409814700762619336056693\
409131813436072830610006822421568399180878828865624130779460\
438617259828853398661927306856293129558704629256045989464076\
110208592569978237366668166654822438426674566555490387538893\
656476099175185704061248678944708728574308512767720849000403\
950411614279621166869036373101/60399838475592326331362752791\
944763132549609694041832059854653129731539771658328168942361\
906568116204357279114901731638612673017179392637587993370268\
468122751057317804766338855060441224492531078338764563745984\
361634534757917619567424588718030226164336198810659807830928\
894950054794919605549933531685874245309484554173084344795097\
778895379979816703495608964775949909264616094661840599063186\
011543131081083532339588386281198484224591916139857808728711\
337072945237794430249025950156217838942697194548707342214906\
621985660080150918372835213775235759078837614090802954692490\
955558620434772673319859076612900166605163593210918785877475\
268380688613826217264936422758722358549436515729050089664820\
517090881544523313666983596465352462319026753145000093740537\
178177489596826835806901560570709618578068241711965931639634\
809586146278457253570314819921037995164438751876277090234639\
821432381946017446571917916673348009411849176259307380401023\
993294177103548682416638846438507436013936091382661874934845\
500838177629920215935612770414110473755964022901968320874940\
92431878821676880656612635392756954758754490670429601208 ];

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question and answers.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42016/algorithms-for-finding-rational-points-on-an-elliptic-curve) I am conjecturing that Cremona's mwrank (which, I believe, is available in sage) will find what you are looking for.

**EDIT** Yes, [available in sage.](http://www.sagenb.org/doc/live/reference/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_rational_field.html)

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for the link.  Unfortunately this particular curve seems to be out of the range achievable (in any reasonable time) by mwrank, or even findinf. Kevin.

Comment: @Kevin: very sad...