# How to find generators to Mordell weil groups of elliptic curves?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am new to branch of elliptic curve and algebraic number theory .I want to find generators to Mordell Weil group of the Elliptic Curve $y^2=x^3-6321363052$ and class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{6321363052}) $.  Some suggestions such as  algorithm or softwares will be  helpful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the software Sage. Please ask in a Sage forum on question/answer site.

Comment: This may be a hard to compute example. Sage indeed gets stuck. Magma reports a lower bound of 1 for the rank, so you might be able to coax it to give you a point of infinite order.

Comment: Try http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/

Comment: I think one prefers to use the algebraic method to compute the 2-Selmer group, as opposed to the invariant method. In Sage, this might be implemented by Simon in PARI. The 2-Selmer group has order 4. It is reasonably easy to find one point on a cover, mapping to an $x$-coordinate $6321363053/3418801$. It is a bit harder to find a second independent point, but one has $x$-coordinate $77367184671463906202575142600893705817/4363223875270025353581185386334464$.

Comment: Thank you for your response will you please elaborate how did you get x-co-ordinate of rational points.

Comment: This is similar to a question Kevin Acres had: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105577/rational-points-on-y2-x3-860695/105591#105591  The same tricks should work, you can do a 3-descent via 3-isogeny and a 4-descent by brute force (assuming GRH will help). Those descents can be patched together with the TwelveDescent command in magma to give you 12-covers of the elliptic curve on which to search for points.