# Why is 1331 the only cube of the form $x^2 + x − 1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

The Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1000_(number)#1300_to_1399) mentions that 1331 is the only cube of the form $x^2 + x − 1$, for $x = 36$. What is the proof?

Comment: It looks like this is an elliptic curve of rank 0 with a torsion subgroup of order 6, so computer algebra software should be able to do this for you.

Comment: let me swap your variables and try to solve y^2 + y  = x^3 + 1. That looks like an elliptic curve, and in fact it's this one: https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/225/c/2

In fact what you write is not quite true, since 0^2 + 0 - 1 = (-1)^3, and 1^2 + 1 - 1 = 1^3. But the solution you've got is sort of the interesting one.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Why? There is non-trivial mathematics here, and the OP knows her mathematics

Comment: Thank you so much. That means, I need to fix the Wikipedia to say that this is the only non-trivial cube of this form.

Comment: To correct Thomas Browning's comment above, the curve is actually rank $1$, so there are infinitely many rational solutions, stating $(61/25, 434/125)$, $(-71/144, 973/1728)$, $(-779/1849, -125945/79507)$ ...

Comment: According to [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/225/c/2), $y^2+y=x^3+1$ has integral solutions as follows.
$ (x,y)=(-1, 0) , (-1, -1) , (1, 1) , (1, -2) , (11, 36) , (11, -37). $
Hence only positive integral solutions are $(x,y)=(1, 1),(11, 36).$
Using generator $(x,y)=(1,1)$, we can get positive rational solutions such as $(61/25, 434/125),(408241/45796, 256170307/9800344),(479399/2739025, 2812459393/4533086375)$.

Comment: @TanyaKhovanova yes; indeed "non-trivial" is vague and it's just better enumerating all solutions including "trivial" ones ($x=-37,-2,-1,0,1,36$ as given in Tomita's comment).

Comment: Could it be predicted just from the defining equation that this list of integers is invariant under the involution $x\mapsto -1-x$?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Yes, the equation $y^3=x^2+x-1$ itself is invariant under $x\mapsto-1-x$ (since $(-1-x)^2+(-1-x)=x^2+x$).

Comment: Does this symmetry provide non trivial information about the curve?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN If you already know this is an elliptic curve, then no - any elliptic curve admits such an order 2 involution (which is just the $P\mapsto -P$ map in the elliptic curve group law)

Comment: For each value of $y$, this is a quadratic equation in $x$; namely,
$x^2+x-(y^3+1)=0$. The necessary and sufficient condition for it to have
integer solutions is that its discriminant is a square (of an integer); that
is, $5+4y^3=z^2$; equivalently, $(4z)^2-(4y)^3=80$. The problem thus boils
down to finding the integer solutions of the equation $u^2-v^3=80$ (and
selecting the solutions with both $u$ and $v$ divisible by $4$.  ...

Comment: ... The
Dipohantine equation $u^2-v^3=k$ is known as *Mordell's equation". It has
been extensively studied; in particular, Mordell has shown that for any
integer $k$ the equation has only a finite number of solutions. For some
values of $k$, Mordell's equation can be solved using an elementary argument,
not appealing to elliptic curves. I do not know whether the case $k=80$
admits an elementary solution, just search the web / arXiv.

Answer (score 17):

Here is the more elementary way that one would have solved this before LLL. I will still use the computer for some calculations, but technically one could do all this by hand. Worse, I won't even do all of the steps, but I hope the part I show explains the method, for those that may be interested. Maybe someone wants to complete it or finds a shorter way.

First, setting $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ with $\theta^2+\theta-1$, a.k.a the Golden ratio, we will rewrite our equation as $$N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(y-\theta) = x^3$$ to be solved in $X$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. The field $K$ has class number 1 and the units are generated by $\theta$. From this, using a little argument about the $\sqrt{5}$-adic valuation, one can show that, there must be a $i\in \{0,1,2\}$ such that $$y-\theta = \theta^i\cdot \alpha^3$$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$, the ring of integers of $K$. Write $\alpha = a+b\,\theta$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and split into the three cases according to $i$.

**Case $i=0$ :** Spanning out $\alpha^3$ and equating the coefficients in front of $\theta$, we get $$\begin{align*} y &= a^3+3ab^2-b^3 \\ -1&=b\cdot(3a^2-3ab+2b^2)\end{align*}$$ Now the second line tells us that $b=\pm 1$, but neither of the choices allows us to find $a$ as an integer, so that case does not occur.

**Case $i=1$ :** This time the equations are $$\begin{align*} y &= 3a^2b-3ab^2+2b^3\\-1 &=a^3-3a^2b+6ab^2-3b^3\end{align*}$$ One can note here aside that the second line is a model of the curve $3$-isogenous to the original curve over $\mathbb{Q}$. This second (Thue) equation, we rewrite as $$-1 = N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(a-b\xi)$$ where $L=\mathbb{Q}(\xi)$ and $\xi^3-3\xi^2+6\xi-3=0$. This $L$ has also trivial class number and the units are generated by $1-\xi$ of norm $1$. We are now looking for units of norm $-1$ in $L$ with no $\xi^2$ term. Once more we split into three cases $j\in\{0,1,2\}$. We want to solve $$a+b\xi = - (1-\xi)^j\cdot(1-\xi)^{3k} = -(1-\xi)^j\cdot(-2+3\xi)^k.$$

**Subcase $j=0$ :** We may rewrite it as $$a-b\xi = - (1+3(\xi-1))^k = -\bigl(1+3(\xi-1)k+9(\xi-1)^2k(k-1)/2 + 27\cdots \bigr)$$ and consider this as a power series in $k$ over $\mathbb{Q}_3(\xi)$, which is a totally ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_3$. We can compare the power series coefficient in front of $\xi^2$, to get an equation of the form $$0=9 k (k-1)\cdot \bigl(1/2 -9/24 (k-2)(k-3)+\cdots\bigr).$$ By Strassmann's theorem, the power series has at most two solutions in $\mathbb{Q}_3$. But it is easy to spot that there are two such solutions, namely $(a=-1,b=0,k=0)$ and $(a=2,b=3,k=1)$. These correspond to $(x,y)=(-1,0)$ and $(11,36)$ repsectively.

**Subcase $j=1$ :** leads to a single solution $a-b\xi=-1+\xi$ which corresponds to $(x,y)=(1,-2)$.

**Subcase $j=2$ :** produces a unit power series and has therefore no solutions.

**Case $i=2$ :** I believe one just gets the $-P$ for all the $P$ found in the case $i=1$. But I admit that I have not checked.

Finally, I should say that for questions on integral points on elliptic curve I often turn to Smart's "The algorithmic Resolution of Diophantine Equations" that explains things well. Like the $3$-adic method used in the subcases in chapter III.

Comment: Regarding the $i=2$ case: Given a solution to $y-\theta = \theta^2 \alpha^3$, rewrite it as $y - \theta = \theta^{-1} \beta^3$ for $\beta = \theta \alpha$. Then apply the Galois automorphism of $K$ to get $y-(1-\theta) = - \theta \beta^3$ or $(1-y) - \theta = \theta \beta^3$. So, if $y$ solves the $i=2$ case then $1-y$ solves the $i=1$ case (and vice versa). And thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 9):

According to SAGE, there are 6 integral points on the curve.

```
sage: EllipticCurve([0,0,1,0,1]).integral_points(both_signs=True)
[(-1 : -1 : 1),(-1 : 0 : 1),(1 : -2 : 1),(1 : 1 : 1),(11 : -37 : 1),(11 : 36 : 1)]
```

Comment: The question is “What is the proof?” — so “Because the computer says so” seems a slightly unsatisfying answer, on its own.  It would be greatly improved by some information about how SAGE computes this, since that’d provide at least a recipe for the proof.  In 5 minutes of Googling I wasn’t easily able to work out what algorithm is used — the best I could find was the [SAGE documentation](https://bit.ly/3zfqV0H) and a couple of old MO answers: https://mathoverflow.net/a/46778/2273, https://mathoverflow.net/a/42044/2273

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: I agree. It is more than nothing though, and the algorithms of SAGE are pretty reliable.

Comment: Oh yes, I completely agree this answer is an excellent starting point!

Comment: See also [How to compute rational or integer points on elliptic curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203484/how-to-compute-rational-or-integer-points-on-elliptic-curves).

Comment: The link to "SAGE documentation" in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394950/why-is-1331-the-only-cube-of-the-form-x2-x-%e2%88%92-1/394996#comment1010835_394996) above points to [Elliptic curves over the rational numbers](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_rational_field.html). Just posting this in case the URL shortener ends up breaking in the future.